# PHP getting results from access not getting dates

Tags: php, ms-access-2010

I'm using the below code to query an access database using PHP.

```
<?php

// Create an instance of the ADO connection object
$conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");

// Define the connection string and specify the database driver
$connStr = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=".realpath("HS_BE.accdb").";";

// Open the connection to the database
$conn->open($connStr);

// Declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT TOP 20 * FROM Valuations WHERE Consultant = '1'";

// Execute the SQL statement and return records
$rs = $conn->execute($query);

$num_columns = $rs->Fields->Count ();
$arrColumns = array();

for ($i=0; $i < $num_columns; $i++) {
    $arrColumns[] = $rs->Fields($i);
    $newArr[] = $rs->Fields($i)->name; 
}

$arrResult = array();

while (!$rs->EOF) {
    $arrRow = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < $num_columns; $i++) {
       $arrRow[$newArr[$i]] = $arrColumns[$i]->value;
    }
    $arrResult[] = $arrRow;

    $rs->MoveNext();
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arrResult);
```

This is half working, all the text fields are returning fine but the date fields are returning as {} with nothing inside, does anyone know why its choosing to ignore the date fields?

EDIT
When i var_dump $arrResult before converting to json, this is what one of the dates is :

```
["Appointment"]=>
    object(variant)#77 (0) {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to add `charset=utf8` to your connection or to `utf8_encode()` the date before you `json_encode()` it.

You could also use:

```
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')
```

before your `SELECT` query.

Comment: It's still doing it, the detais just "11:00 AM" and "04-Apr-12" anything like that isn't showing but i have a telephone number collumn which is returning fine

Comment: How does it return before json_encode()? Whats the date look like in $arrResult?

Answer (score 0):

i did this :

```
$arrRow[$newArr[$i]] = (string)$arrColumns[$i]->value;
```

Converting it to a string and it worked